# Unity home icon replaced with grey file cabinet

Tags: unity, nautilus

Somehow I managed to remove the Home icon from my Unity bar. I ran nautilus and locked its icon onto the bar. This works like before but the problem is the icon I am getting is the grey file cabinet, rather than the Home icon.

I tried several things I found on the net, but nothing. BTW, I don't have a "nautilus.desktop" under /usr/share/applications. The closest filename I have is "Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool". Not critical but any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean just the icon? The **Files** icon has changed recently through regular updates. [This news on OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/ubuntu-13-04-updates-nautilus-update-tool-icons?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+d0od+%28OMG!+Ubuntu!%29)

Answer (score 1):

Icons and themes are stored in the same format using the same file names for the components. Applications don't really need to be aware of an icon itself, just the name. Icons are in /usr/share/icons/{icon set name}/ for example the Faenza icon for GIMP is /usr/share/icons/Faenza/apps/scalable/gimp.svg. /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop is the launcher for the gimp application. Within gimp.desktop is the command:

```
Icon=gimp
```

The system will decide what file extension to use. If you wished to change that icon you would do so in /usr/share/icons/Faenza/apps/scalable/gimp.svg. The Home folder icon is at /usr/share/icons/Faenza/places/scalable/user-home.svg.

Comment: There is no Faenza sufolder under /usr/share/icons here. There is /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places with subfolders named as 16, 24 etc (these are sizes I believe), and some of these contain user-home.svg. There is no "scalable" subfolder though.

Comment: Sorry for using an example with icons not included in the default release. You can certainly use Humanity icons if you choose. FYI Faenza are available by running the following two lines in a terminal window:    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme